# Far Cry 3 Sniper Challenge not working?

Tags: far-cry-3

So I know I'm a few years late for playing FC3, but I'm finding that this "sniper challenge" just east and slightly north of Dr. Earnhardt's mansion gets me awkwardly stuck. I accept the mission, I have my gun, but I can't move anywhere (I'm rooted to the spot I spawn at), and I can't zoom in. I can fire, but what's the point of firing a sniper rifle if you can't zoom in? Additionally, I'm guessing since I can't move, no one ever shows up to try to shoot. Any ideas?